# gitbash wont display messages from hook

Tags: githooks, git-bash

I recently added a pre-receive hook to a git repository, and the hook works just fine preventing commits when it needs to. When a push is denied, I want the user to see a message telling them why. My script has a few print statements that display the message I want, however, **these messages do not show up in the gitbash terminal of the committer**.

The messages *are* being produced, the daemon process is printing them out, I see the messages when pushing from a unix terminal, and I also see the messages in a popup in Eclipse if I push using the built-in eGit tool, so I don't think the script is the issue.

I have tried running the daemon in unix, and on windows in gitbash, with the same results.
My hook is written in python, but I've tried others without success.

The closest I could find in my searches was this issue with Tortoise Git: https://tortoisegit.org/issue/1027. The cause called out for this was a UNIX vs windows line ending quirk, but since I have tried this in a windows to windows setup, I don't think line endings are the culprit.

*Update*: This issue only occurs when I have configured remote with the git:// protocol. Using ssh:// works, the hook message shows in the gitbash terminal.

How do I get my hook messages to display in the gitbash terminal?